# __VIEWSTATE response in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am sending a image to webserver using following code. and in string viewstate i get "/wEPDwUKLTQwMjY2MDA0M2RkXtxyHItfb0ALigfUBOEHb/mYssynfUoTDJNZt/K8pDs=" as a response. But I want the URL . How Can I achieve this.

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
            byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
            //System.out.println("byte array:"+image);

            String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
            //System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "********";

            String response = "";


            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024; 
            String mimeType = "image/jpeg";

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("url");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



                  conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);


                    DataOutputStream dos;
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   // dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"__VIEWSTATE\"\r\n\r\n" );


                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + img_str +"\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    //FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(img_str);
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                    // retrieve the response from server
                    int ch;

                    StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                    while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){ b.append( (char)ch ); }
                     s=b.toString();
                    Log.i("Response",s);
                    dos.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return s;
        }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
     int i = 0;
     String viewstate = "";
     while (true){
         int found = s.indexOf("\"__VIEWSTATE\"", i);
         if (found == -1) break;
         int start = found + 38; //check numbers from start of "__V"
         int end  = (s.indexOf("/>", start)) -2;
         viewstate = s.substring(start, end);
         i = end + 1;  
         Log.e("VIEW STATE", viewstate);

         StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
         builder.append(image);
         builder.append(viewstate);
         String a= builder.toString();
         System.out.println(a);
    super.onPostExecute(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post an example URL please?

Edit: int found = s.indexOf("\"__VIEWSTATE\"", i); returns the index of the first matched pattern. So if you wan't to get the url, you should use viewstate = s.substring(0, found);